# Reading byte Array from text file and saving as PDF is corrupting the PDF

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need to convert a PDF file into byte array and save it in a text file.
Then I need to read the text file and revive the PDF file.

For this I am using the below code (I am using UTF8 for writing the text file).

```
using System.Text;

string SourceFile = @"C:\\Files\\originalfile.pdf";
string SerializedFile = @"C:\\Files\\serialized.txt";
string RevivedFile = @"C:\\Files\\revived.pdf";

SerializeFile(SourceFile, SerializedFile);
DeSerializeFile(SerializedFile, RevivedFile);

//Serialize
static void SerializeFile(string SourceFilePath, string SerializedFilePath)
{
    byte[] SourceBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(SourceFilePath);
    File.WriteAllText(SerializedFilePath, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(SourceBytes));
    Console.WriteLine("Serialized File created");
}


//De-Serialize
static void DeSerializeFile(string SerializedFilePath, string RevivedFilePath)
{       
    byte[] RevivedBytes;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(SerializedFilePath))
    {
        RevivedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(RevivedFilePath, RevivedBytes);
    Console.WriteLine("File Revived.");
}
```

The serialized file is generating successfully, but the second part (Revived File) is getting corrupted.

How can I correctly restore the PDF file ?

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions - in particular, your use of PascalCase for variable names is really distracting.) Oh, and I suspect you don't *actually* want verbatim string literals with double backslashes - either `@"C:\Files\originalfile.pdf"` or `"C:\\Files\\originalfile.pdf"` would be fine, but there's no reason to combine the two...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: don't treat opaque binary data as text.

Use `File.WriteAllBytes` instead of `File.WriteAllText` in your `SerializeFile` method, and *just* use `File.ReadAllBytes` in `DeSerializeFile`.

Your code currently *assumes* that you can treat all data as UTF-8-encoded text, converting between bytes and strings with no loss of information. That's simply not the case, because not every byte sequence is valid UTF-8 data.

It's unclear why you even *want* to convert the data to text, given that you're really just copying files.

If for some reason you *actually* need to represent opaque data as text, you should use base64 or some similar mechanism, which *is* a reversible transform: bytes -> base64 -> bytes will always preserve all the data, regardless of what that data is. (Assuming a correct implementation etc, of course.)